# Geometric Sequence Nearly Complete

Tags: sequences-and-series

The 5th Term of a geometric progression or series is 162 and the 8th term is 4374, find the series.

$$ar^4 = 162$$
$$ar^7 = 4374$$
$$\frac {ar^7}{ar^4} = \frac {4374}{162} = 27$$
$$r^{7 -4} = r^3$$
$$r^3 = 27$$
$$3\sqrt27$$
$$r = 3\sqrt3$$
$$a(3)^4 = 81$$
$$a = 1$$

I have this so far but it doesn't add up. Can some tell me where i have gone wrong please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r^3=27$ implies $r=\sqrt[3]{27}=3$. Thus then $ar^4=162\\a(3)^4=162\\a\cdot81=162\\a=2$

Comment: I was getting 81, just then wasn't sure. Thanks. So is the series 2?

Comment: The series is a geometric series with first term $a=2$, common ratio $3$. The terms are thus $2,6,18,54,162...$